# python to add variables to list by identifying from a line

Tags: python

I am new to python and i want to know how to identify variables in python from a single line and add to list.

consider:I have a line from  a program

```
self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You clicked the button)" )
```

i should get the variables as :

```
labelvariable
entryvariable
```

This has to be added to the list,please help answers would be appreciated

Comment: The semantics of your question are a bit confusing. When you say "I should get the variables as", what do you mean by this?

Comment: i mean the variables should be added to list by their names.that s what i meant.

Comment: What for you need variables names on list ?

Comment: because to check same variable repeats in a program

Comment: So you don't need variable names for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some objects (probably in `Tkinter`)

```
self.labelVariable
self.entryVariable
```

so you can do

```
my_list = [ self.labelVariable, self.entryVariable ]
```

and when you do

```
self.labelVariable.set("new value")
self.entryVariable.set("new value 2")
```

then you can get results from list too

```
for x in my_list:
   print x.get()
```

.

```
new value
new value 2
```

Comment: infact my question is,how do i first add variables to list by identifying them as variable?because i have lots of other stuffs which are not variables,thats why i asked.

Comment: You could use `type(variable)` to see what type is it but there are a lot of types. Variable with integer number gives you `int`, the same variable with list gives you `list` etc.